# Image inside a button not positioned correctly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have the following markup:

```
<p class="managebox">
  <button value="Add page">
    <img src="page_add.png" alt="Add more content" />
    Add Page
  </button>
</p>
```

And the following CSS:

```
p.managebox { position: relative; }
p.managebox button { display: block;
                     padding: 5px 7px 4px 30px;
                     position: relative; }
p.managebox button img { position: absolute; left: 7px; }
```

#### In IE 8 I get this:

[IE8 http://tinypic.com/images/404.gif](http://tinypic.com/images/404.gif)

#### In Chrome 4.0 I get this:

[Chrome http://tinypic.com/images/404.gif](http://tinypic.com/images/404.gif)

#### In Firefox 3.6 I get this:

[image: Firefox 3.6]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? One thing I've just realised that may be relevant - if I use an `a` instead of `button`, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never seen this problem, but for those particular pusposes I usually use `background-image`. Give it a try.

**Update**: just tried an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). I actually didn't need any style to get it to be positioned the same in all browsers.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2397413</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button value="Add">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/Calendar_add.png" width="16" height="16">
            Add
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So do I, not sure why I opted to do otherwise here - I can make that change, but I'd really like to know/understand *why*.

Comment: Maybe a FF bug. In all the other browsers from IE6 and up (Safari, Chrome, Opera) it indeed works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, p.managebox button img seems to be inheriting some CSS. Use FireBug to inspect the element and see what CSS is being applied. Looks like align though.

Comment: What difference would `align` make if `img` is positioned absolutely?

Comment: It shouldn't that is why I would look at FireBug and see what is actually being applied.